# Is it possible to custom jquery datatables row rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have this code :

```
$('#tblProduct').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        processing: true,
        pageLength: 5,
        ajax: {
            url: BASE_URL + 'Product/Index/',
            type: 'POST'
        },
        columns: [
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a class="mazl-br" href="/Product/' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a class="mazl-cm">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            }
        ]
```

Datatables will always render every columns inside `<tr>`, is it possible if I want to get rid of `<tr>` and render it with my own custom style instead like `<div>`?

Comment: Not sure this is possible - what are you trying to achieve? There's bound to be another way.

Comment: In short : no.  dataTables entire logic is built up on a `<table>` markup structure, so that is beyond any plugin, hack or monkey patch to do that.